# automated change password on linux servers

Tags: linux, redhat, password, shell-scripting, operating-system

Dear friends and colleges

Each half year we need to change the password on our redhat Linux servers ,

we have 8723 servers!!! In our company

Is it possible to automate password changing each half year without our involving ?

Regarding the password name – how to know it , so it very simple only one server from all our server will get this password , lets say in /var/pass/pass.txt

**Is it wonderful innovation ?**

Comment: You actually use passwords to manage your servers?

Comment: each half year I use expect script and run it on all our serves , but this take time

Comment: You should use SSH keys like Gerald indirectly implied.

Comment: just publish your answer so I can select your answer as the best answer

Comment: Also you urgently need to look into config management tools.

Comment: @Sven can you please let is know more about this - your opinion is very important to us

Comment: Look up Puppet, Ansible, Chef (others exists) to learn more about some popular config management tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, with 8723 servers you should already have some automation and configuration management and if you don't: this is a perfect use-case to start introducing it. Resetting local (root) passwords is fairly trivial to automate with tools Puppet, chef, Ansible, Red Hat Satellite etc.

---

Alternatives:

1. Replace local (management) accounts with centralised authentication in the form of LDAP, FreeIPA, radius or even AD. That results in only a single place where to enforce password policies and/or reset passwords for your admins and users.
2. Configure `sudo` with access rights based on group membership and nobody needs to know or use the actual root password(s) anymore, negating the need both set a valid/known root password or to ever change that password.
3. In the rare cases that you would need actual root access you can boot in single user mode or from a rescue image (or follow the [RHEL7 root password recovery procedure](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Changing_and_Resetting_the_Root_Password) )
4. If you do need valid root paswords  look in to [privileged password management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileged_identity_management) software which  automates securely storing passwords and controlling access to them. Typically such a system will also periodically reset privileged account passwords and after an admin was granted access to a system such software will also reset the password again, to deny the admin future access

Comment: the most great answer that I seen never , thx a lot